Streamlit cant pickle load my custom object
## Packages
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit as st

## Pathing
main_path = Path(__file__).parent.parent
file_path = main_path / 'out' / 'data.pickle'

## Load portfolio
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    pf = pickle.load(file)
st.title("Hello")

I have this simple script that pickle loads an object that I created using a custom_library. I can run this file with Python. However, when I try to run it with streamlit, I get an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_library'
Why are they behaving differently and how can I fix this?

Is your custom library pip installed? (unpickling requires having access to the classes that were pickled before, and the data structures cannot have changed between picking and unpickling)

To be sure you have custom_library available, just import it
## Packages
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit as st
import custom_library
...

